# My animation is shaking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

I am doing this Blenderguru tutorial on making fire. I have done most except the stuff with with campfire sticks but when I play the animation in Object mode (rendered) the whole scene is shaking and I also think the speed of the animation it too high. What is wrong with my my settings ? 
The scene is not shaking in Solid shading, only when displayed in Rendered shading

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why this is a bad question ? If I understand that I will try to avoid it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

You can't playback cycles renders in realtime. The frame is only displayed for a fraction of a second, and it takes about 10 seconds to completely render.

Long winded version:

I just looked at the blend file. I notice that when the 3D viewport render is set to Solid 
[image] (white sphere)

that it plays ok on my machine. When I switch the viewport to Render [image] (gold sphere)

the animation is really chaotic.

This is because, it's taking cycles longer to render the frame, than it is for Blender's playback to jump to the next one.

So, cycles starts to render the image, gets about halfway through the first pass, and blender says: 'go to the next frame'. So, cycles stops rendering the current frame, dumps a bunch of garbage on the screen and starts rendering the next frame.

When the animation is rendered, 'Scene -> Render -> Animation'  it actually looks quite nice. it's stable.

Your animation is set to 24 fps. If you set it any slower, it will be choppy in the final render.